# Finding a specific improper integral on a solution path to a 2 dimensional system of ODEs

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, improper-integrals, dynamical-systems

In my study of dynamical systems I was recently met with this system of ODEs:

> $ \dot{x}=\frac{\sinh{(y)}}{\cosh{(y)}+A\cos{(x)}} $
>
> $ \dot{y}=\frac{A\sin{(x)}}{\cosh{(y)}+A\cos{(x)}} $

for a parameter A satisfying $ 0 < A < 1 $
Now clearly $ (0,0) $ and $ (2\pi,0) $ are fixed points and we may check there is a solution (heteroclinic) path (curve) from $ (0,0) $ to $ (2\pi,0) $. I need to find its representation not as a curve but via time dependency meaning (x(t),y(t)), I also know via simple integration that the solution sits on the equation curve $ \cosh{(y)} = -A\cos{(x)} + (A+1) $ but I cannot solve these equations for x,y components specifically as it seems impossible. Finally I need to determine if the following Melnikov integral has simple zeros: $ M(t_0)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} -\frac{A}{A+1}\sin{(x(t))}\sin{(\omega(t+t_0))} dt $, where x(t) is the x component of the solution curve mentioned earlier. I do not have $ x(t) $ explicitly let alone handle this integral. Maybe it can be handled via perturbation or numerical analysis (I only need to know if it has any simple zeros). I figured a good first step was to solve for x(t) via the equation $ \dot{x}=\frac{\sinh{(y)}}{\cosh{(y)}+A\cos{(x)}} = \frac{\sqrt{(A\cos{(x)}-A-1)^2-1}}{A+1} $ which is the equation on the solution curve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT :

Equation of the trajectory : $y(x)=\cosh^{-1}\left(-A\cos(x)+A+1\right)$
$$y(x)=\ln \left|\left(-A\cos(x)+A+1\right)\pm\sqrt{\left(-A\cos(x)+A+1\right)^2-1}\:\right|$$
Implicit equation of the motion : 
$$t=(A+1)\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{\left(-A\cos(x)+A+1\right)^2-1}} $$
After some calculus with help of WolframAlpha :
$$t=-(A+1)\sqrt{\frac{2}{A(1-\cos(x))}}\sin(\frac{x}{2})\tanh^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{-A\cos(x)+A+2}}\cos(\frac{x}{2}) \right)+C$$
$C=$constant. For example, if $x=\pi$ at $t=t_m$ then $C=t_m$

As far as I know there is no closed form for the inverse function $x(t)$.

IN ADDITION :
$$ M(t_0)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} -\frac{A}{A+1}\sin{(x(t))}\sin{(\omega(t+t_0))} dt $$

$dt=(A+1)\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\left(-A\cos(x)+A+1\right)^2-1}} $

$$ M(t_0)=-A\int_0^{2\pi} \sin{(x)}\sin{(\omega(t(x)+t_0))} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{\left(-A\cos(x)+A+1\right)^2-1}}  $$
where $t(x)=-(A+1)\sqrt{\frac{2}{A(1-\cos(x))}}\sin(\frac{x}{2})\tanh^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{-A\cos(x)+A+2}}\cos(\frac{x}{2}) \right)$

Comment: Thank you for this part, could you please help me in finding that improper integral as without a closed form for x I cannot really get at it

Comment: I mean the Melnikov integral $ M(t_0)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} -\frac{A}{A+1}\sin{(x(t))}\sin{(\omega(t+t_0))} dt $

Comment: Why do you need the Melnikov integral in this case ? All is analytically known on parametric form : $t(x)$ and $y(x)$ with parameter $x$.

Comment: I need the Melnikov integral in its own place it is important to me for predicting chaos this is part of my problem

Comment: So I mean Melnikov's integral is important to me, the important part of the question

Comment: OK. I am afraid that the integral be rather complicated. Just change of variable on the integral : $dx$ instead of $dt$ since $t(x)$ is explicit. See the integral in addition to my previous answer : horrible !

Comment: Right the integral is troy awful but I am only interested in finding if it has any simple zeros

Comment: Well, good luck !